# Lambda to create list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe, lambda

I'm trying to find a faster way to loop over a larger CSV file other than a for loop.  So far I have this.

```
df['Element'].apply(lambda x: x == 'TMAX', 
                              dates.append(df['Date']), 
                              highs.append(df['Data_Value']))
```

It works but only prints out true or false. 
I can print dates and that work but just the dates list.
Same with highs. Whats the best way to create a list or dict that show the date and value as a pair?

Comment: Do you mean `df[df['Element'] == 'TMAX'][['Date', 'Data_Value']]`?

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: This worked for me thank you!
`df[df['Element'] == 'TMAX'][['Date', 'Data_Value']]`